# Generating CDR records from CUCM 9.x

Tags: calllog, cucm

I followed the following link to output CDR records to my call logging server via sFTP : http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/voice_ip_comm/cucm/service/9_1_1/car/CUCM_BK_C28A807A_00_cdr-analysis-reporting-admin-guide91_chapter_01.html

Both publisher and subscriber were configured to send data to the call logging server.

The call logging server received 19674 records from the Call Manager, but only 25 records are of CDR type and the rest are of CMR type.

From my experience, I would expect at much higher number of CDR type records. Additionally, there were certainly more than 25 calls were made/received on the CUCM extensions/gateways.

Are there any settings that need to be configured on the CUCM in order to generate the rest of CDRs? Should I configure only Publisher or only Subscriber to generate CDR? Is there a way of switching off CMR type records?

Comment: Not a programming question

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that CDRs are in fact enabled, You likely have a very long "CDR File Interval".  You could set this to once a day, which would only send over one CDR a day (they'd be huge though).

Look here:
Callmanager -> Cisco Unified CM Administration -> System -> Enterprise Parameters

CDR File Time Interval - Set this to 1 minute (which is the default)

Answer (score 0):

If you look under system parameters there is a "CDR Enable Flag" which is disabled by default.  The CDR DB is updated across all systems so you do not need to setup the offload on multiple servers.  The CMR records are records on call quality average jitter MOS scores etc and would be referenced by callid